# Install AMD Catalyst drivers in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, ati, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I have an ATI Radeon HD Series Graphics Card on my system. The question is:

What is the proper way to install the latest AMD Catalyst drivers in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo. Thanks for your flag and the effort you put into answering. I think the most prudent thing to do would be mark this question as a duplicate of the other question and also delete the answer in this question. Hope you are fine with that. Thanks again for your contributions.